# .Net SDK Wrapper for Sitecore SSC REST API Item Service

Tags: sitecore-api, sitecore-services-client, item-web-api

As we know, Sitecore provides the `ItemService` [[link]](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/en/the-itemservice.html) for developers to have a REST API interface for interacting with Sitecore items.

What I am trying to achieve is to consume this REST Api from the other .net server outside of the Sitecore solution.

I am wondering if there is any SDK or client library available that I can utilize in my code to speed up the development.

Ideally if I could feed it with my Sitecore website Url and credentials and be able to use it just like that: `SitecoreService.AddItem(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to look on [Sitecore Mobile SDK](https://github.com/Sitecore/sitecore-mobile-ssc-sdk#code-snippet). IIRC, it supposed to do what you request but the project looks a bit outdated... Last commit a year ago.

Comment: Thanks Serhii, looks like what I need!